# When I upgraded the dart language I get an error in doesn't support null safety from the universal_ui package

Tags: flutter, dart

When I tried to run this transaction:   flutter pub add universal_ui

I get this error:

> The current Dart SDK version is 3.0.0-204.0.dev.
>
> Because pt_proj depends on universal_ui any which doesn't support null safety, version solving failed.
>
> The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.7.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety.
> For details, see https://dart.dev/null-safety

How can I solve it?

Comment: Why are you trying to add such an old package? Last update is 2 years ago. I think the best here is to try and see if you can stop using that package in your project.

Comment: Because I added an HTML page in the flutter, and I don't find any package like it. @julemand101

Comment: What package are you trying to add?

Comment: I used dart:ui package to show HTML page in the web view, but I want to show it in the mobile view also, so I am trying to add univesal_ui package. @julemand101

Comment: You need to find another solution. If you really think the package will be useful for your project, you need to fork the package (you can download the files from https://pub.dev/packages/universal_ui/versions) and make it null-safe. But after a quick look at the package, I very much doubt it solves any problems that is still relevant today. At least, you can really easily just do what the package does directly in your project and not depend on this package at all.

Answer (score 0):

upgrade your flutter and update pub spec.yaml file

sdk: ">=3.0.0 <4.0.0"

for :
*Because pt_proj depends on universal_ui any which doesn't support null safety, version solving failed.*

flutter 3 require null-safe packages so try to find another package support null-safety  with same functionality to universal_ui. or simply you can clone package's code and use it in your project , especially, if the package does not depend on Native code